# Automating Javascript Commands in Browser

Tags: javascript, database, browser

EDIT:
After some advice I'm now trying to write a greasemoneky script to automate a button click on a web interface. The javascript command I'm trying to automate is:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UltraWebTab1$_ctl1$grdExpressQuery$GridView1','ProductExpand$1')
```

I don't know how to program but I managed to scrape this together from examples found online

```
var txt='ProductExpand$';

 for (i=1; i<1000; i++)
{
 doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UltraWebTab1$_ctl1$grdExpressQuery$GridView1',txt+i);
}
```

The script is not working, if I could get some general guidance or advice on how to go about this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use GreasyMonkey addon for Firefox to run userscripts.

Comment: I don't think this solves the issue. The asker probably has no idea how to write a userscript.

Comment: Correct I don't know how to write a script but if you give me a general guideline or hint I can scrape something together. So far I created a var called txt and a for loop, in the for loop i changed the 'ProductExpand$1' to txt+1. It's not working tho, any advice?

Comment: Open javascript console in browser and see if there's error. I assume it needs time to load so you need to run it asyncronously with interval, using setTimeout(): `var txt='ProductExpand$'; var i=1; function loadMore() {doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UltraWebTab1$_ctl1$grdExpressQuery$GridView1',txt+i); i++; if(i<1000) setTimeout(loadMore,3000)}`

Comment: overloop, thank you I got it working! I tried upvoting your answer but I don't have enough reputation. You have a wonderful week!